# Create authentication using database in firebase from android app

Tags: android, firebase

I am building a smart lock, which can be controlled through an Android mobile application. I want to add a new user, this new user will have a name,email and a password. I want to store these details in a database at firebase, using the data from the database I want to login using email and password from android app, also I want to view the list of all the users registered from the android app, update their details, delete a user. I just know how to create authentication using email and password only, but I cannot view them or delete them or change its credentials from the android app.

Answer (score 0):

Later I have same problem. You can use Firebase Database. To add it you must open tools tab in android studio and connect app to firebase by instruction. Then you just write code. Look at [this](https://github.com/vlad2711/storageOfInformation/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/kram/vlad/storageofinformation/mvp/model/firebase/FirebaseHelper.java)
. 
As I say create app with "same" functional and at this link you can see my firebase helper class you can see all code that you need.